# Android Automotive Emulator "no system images installed for this target"

Tags: android-emulator, android-automotive

I have installed Android Studio 3.5 from the stable channel. I am trying to build the Android Automotive Emulator but I am receiving the following error

> no system images installed for this target

I have downloaded the following system image

> Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

This image is shown when I try to make a phone/tablet emulator. I am using  Mac Mojave. Do I need to install the Android 10 system image to solve this error?

Comment: Hi there, did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem recently.

Comment: please post the answer if you found.

Comment: Sorry, no answer found yet, I am trying to build the emulator from the aosp site instead

Comment: @Shaan_B  I have twitted to several people, let's see. Can you please tell how to build emulator from AOSP?  is it possible to share if any material links?

Comment: hi @Selva can you please create this as a new question, I will share the links and steps to create the emulator

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58057045/android-aosp-automotive-emulator

Comment: @Selva did you get any answers on Twitter? Or could you link those questions, to make it possible to monitor these?

Comment: sadly, no @user3448282

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are not on the Canary channel for Android Studio, so you are not receiving updates for the Automotive Image. Your Android Studio version is only receiving updates for stable releases of Android. This can be fixed by switching over to the Canary channel in the Android Studio Preferences or downloading the Canary version.

Go to 'Android Studio >> Preferences >> Appearance & Behavior >> System Settings >> Updates'. From there you should a drop-down menu for "Automatically check updates for 'Stable Channel'". Go to the drop-down menu and switch over to 'Canary Channel'.

Another solution is to download the Canary version of Android Studio listed here: https://developer.android.com/studio/archive. Look for the releases that are labelled 'Canary'.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. The channel is for studio updates, I'm not sure it's related to which system images are being downloaded. In any case, this doesn't help me at all, no system images suitable for car simulators show up after this, but I did get an offer to download a beta version of AS.

Comment: I would recommend installing the Canary version separately from your stable version. After download/install, I went directly to the AVD Manager and was able to create an auto emulator with a system image. I can now use it in my stable-version setup.

Comment: Automotive emulator system image for API 33 is now available in stable version of Android Studio. PTAL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370132/automotive-intel-x86-atom-system-image-not-showing-in-android-studio-dolphin/74412420#74412420

Answer (score 36):

For Automotive OS (not Android Auto) you must add system image (at the moment only for Volvo Polestar 2 image)

1. In Android Studio, select Tools > SDK Manager
2. Click the **SDK Update Sites** tab
3. Click **Add** icon
4. Enter the following Name and URL, then click OK

**Name:** `Polestar 2 System Image`
**URL:** `https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar2-sys-img.xml`

Click Apply, then click OK and create a car AVD

Comment: You need to use Canary channel not a stable build (as commented above)

Comment: >create a car AVD: In my case, Polestar AVD could only be added via the search bar (by entering Polestar) in Virtual Device Configuration, not via Category-> Automotive

Comment: As of Android Studio 4.2.2, I didn't need a Canary build of Android Studio to get this to work.

Answer (score 8):

I had a very similar issue and wrote a little guide how I solved it : https://maltewolfcastle.medium.com/how-to-setup-an-automotive-android-emulator-f287a4061b19

Basically I had to import the device profile that comes with the Polestar 2 system image. You can select that from the Table category then and run any Automotive System Image you installed with it.

Comment: Although you are the author of the article you need to keep in mind links may become broken in the future and render your answer obsolete. Posting the images here aswel is likely to help you preventing downvoters or bot flagging for low quality answer marking of the answer. EoR.

Answer (score 8):

Android Automotive emulator :-> you need to add system image of polestar and for that select Tools > SDK Manager
Then , Click the SDK Update Sites tab
Now Click on Add Icon

Enter Name and Url for image

Name: Polestar 2 System Image
URL: https://developer.polestar.com/sdk/polestar2-sys-img.xml

Comment: This worked for me thanks! I think I also needed to install the Android Pie SDK as well.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it to work on a stable release (3.5.1).

I went to `Android Studio > Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools` and then selected `Android Auto API Simulators` and `Android Auto Desktop Head Unit emulator`. Then, back in the `AVD Manager`, I was able to select and download `Pie` for the system image.

Comment: I still can’t get an auto system image and i’ve done exactly this. Any suggestions?

Comment: This works, it's currently only in the Android 9 SDK though, not 10.

Comment: This is for Android Auto, not Android Automotive. Blame Google for the naming confusion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can download API 33 Android Automotive system image from stable version of Android Studio. PTAL [Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image not showing In Android Studio Dolphin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74370132/automotive-intel-x86-atom-system-image-not-showing-in-android-studio-dolphin/74412420#74412420) for more detail.

Update @ Jan 12 2024

- Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1
- From this version, you can use "Automotive (1080p landscape)" device config for Automotive
- And, you can download Android Automotive TM emulator system image for x86_64 and arm64