# Android Automotive Arm_86 is not listed in Virtual Devices

Tags: android-studio, android-automotive

I've been working on android automotive application but emulator is not yet setup due to unknown reason. I have tried the documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57968790/11230348) and i'm using canary channel. After downloading the image for automotive.

[image]

it's not listed under virtual devices.

[image]

I'm using android studio version 4.0.1, how to resolve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved for me by using Android Studio version 4.2 Canary 8 to set up my automotive emulator. Download Android studio version 4.2 Canary alongside Android Studio 4.0.1 if you prefer the stable release.

Then, in version 4.2 you can create an automotive virtual device (same way you tried above) that will then be available for use in both canary and stable releases of android studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you update to Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1, you can use "Automotive (1080p landscape)" device config for Automotive And, you can download Android Automotive TM emulator system image for x86_64 and arm64 by using it.