# Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image not showing In Android Studio Dolphin

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

Automotive Intel x86 Atom System Image not showing In Android Studio Dolphin

I am trying to test an App for android auto, I have downloaded the polestar Image but the generic system image is not found.

I am referring to this

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/testing#generic-images

this is the list of available system images that I am getting on my android studio

[image: this is the list of available system images]

**How can we get the generic system image installed for Android Studio Dolphin**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Updates @ Feb 16, 2024]

If you use [Android Studio Canary Jellyfish](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview), you can see new Android Automotive Portrait emulator device configuration in AVD device manager.

[Updates @ Feb 2, 2024]

Automotive API 33 (Android 13) emulator updated as rev2. You can update it through SDK manager, but need to check "Show Packages Detail" as like the below screen capture.
[image]

[Updates @ Jan 12, 2024]

If you update to Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 1, you can use "Automotive (1080p landscape)" device config for Automotive
And, you can download Android Automotive TM emulator system image for x86_64 and arm64 by using it.

[Updates @ Oct 26, 2023]

Now, you can download Android Automotive API level 33 (Android 13) system image from stable version of Android Studio. But, you can't create AVD by using existing default Automotive hardware config. To resolve this issue, clone device of "Automotive (1024p landscape)" and select "Android Automotive" from cloned device type.

1. Clone Automotive default hardware config.
   [image]
2. Select "Android Automotive" in device type and finish.
   [image]
3. Use this cloned hardware for Automotive system image API level 33.

---

Comment: Not sure if the issue is on my side, but when trying to download AAOS on Linux using AS Jellyfish I can't see the image for x86_64. The one for ARM 64 appears though.

The remote package is available in the xml SDK Update site.

Comment: For my case, when I create new AVD using virtual device manager with "Automotive / Automotive Portrait", virtual device configuration dialog shows recommended tab with Android Automotive TM emulator image for x86_64 as download icon. Tested using Jellyfish preview.

Comment: Please use "Automotive (1080p landscape)" device without PlayStore icon for landscape display.